# How to use Slickgrid to render XML data?

Tags: jqgrid, grid, slickgrid, xmlreader, datastore

We are using JQuery and JQuery UI and looking to rewrite a xml to dom table into a datastore based grid.  In ExtJs, I can use Ext.data.reader.Xml along with a data Modal to map the returned data to the grid.  I am trying to do the same, but using a JQuery based grid library.  Performance and theming also need to be considered.

I have used JqGrid in the past, it has the xmlmap option.  But, I am looking at SlickGrid, specially for its performance capabilities.  I could not see any XML driven examples.  I suspect if I go with Slickgrid I will have to load the xml and loop through it to build the the data object.

Do anyone have suggestions for using Slickgrid to show XML data.  Specifically, does it have xmlmap or xml reader features?  Would SlickGrid give significant performance improvement over JqGrid for say 1000 rows?

Example of XML:

```
            <D:prop>
            <FileExtension>.s4d</FileExtension>
            <ComponentType>DynamicTrove</ComponentType>
            <getcontenttype>application/xml</getcontenttype>
            <ComponentCreatedOn>2011-03-17 12:57:57 </ComponentCreatedOn>
            </D:prop>
            <D:prop>
            <FileExtension>.s4d2</FileExtension>
            <ComponentType>DynamicTrove2</ComponentType>
            <getcontenttype>application/xml2</getcontenttype>
            <ComponentCreatedOn>2011-03-17 12:57:57 2</ComponentCreatedOn>
            </D:prop>
```

Thank you.

Example of

Comment: Do you have XML files as files? Can you provide the data per URL (like http)? An example of XML files are really helpful. For example are namespaces of XSD are used in the files? Have all the XML data the same XSD stucture? Are the data more attribute oriented or all the data are inside of elements? Do you have mixed nodes in the XML files? And so on?

Comment: The XML is currently being loaded to the DOM (ex ActiveXObject).  With bit more rework we should be able to load it using Ajax.  The backend is Java Servlets.

Comment: For jqGrid DOM is OK, but one need have an example of XML to speak more about some grids.

Comment: The returned XML is not too complicated, with each data node containing 15 elements of info.  Depth 1.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display such XML data in a grid. I recommend you to include local searching and filtering which could be very practical for the user if the user have to analyse 1000 rows of data. If you would use paging with filtering you will get very good performance for 1000 rows. I don't recommend you to display all 1000 rows at once. Paging is much better.

The main problem could be XML namespaces because it could be parsed in different ways with respect of jQuery. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10979536/315935) for short description of the problem.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/XmlInjqGrid_.htm) is an example which can be your starting point. [Another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/XmlInjqGrid_.htm) uses XML namespaces and work correct in IE, but it works incorrect in Google Chrome.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I was trying with JSGrid, and XML namespaces are definitely an issue.  I do not need Google Chorme support, thus this would work for me.

Comment: @Natkeeran: You are welcome! The problem of browser independent selection of XML namespaces is not specific for jqGrid. It's jQuery problem.